# How mouse button re-mappings work?

Tags: windows, drivers, mouse, computer-architecture, remapping

I installed my new mouse (Anker 2000 DPI Wireless) and then the driver which installs a program named '5-button mouse' that allows me to remap what each button does, standard stuff and everything works fine.

But it got me wondering where are the settings for what each button does stored? I presumed the registry but was unable to find anything and after looking online they don't seem to be stored there.

Looking at the mouse in device manager and it is using the generic mouclass.sys and mouhid.sys drivers that come with Windows so I'm just wondering how these drivers know what I want each button to do?

For example if I change one of the side buttons to cut rather than copy, where are these settings stored and how do the drivers know where they are?

I know the whole driver stack is very complicated but I would appreciate if someone could just give a basic overview of the process.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it something to do with a filter driver that hooks the mouse ISR?

Comment: It's nothing about storing anywhere. The mappings might be stored or just remembered by the software. Check that the software is always open while you use the shortcuts. Try using to close the program completely and the try the shortcuts. It might be that the software must be running in order for the shortcuts to work properly and so there might not be a need to store the mappings anywhere (registry or any type of file).

Comment: It can also be done directly in hardware on some high-end gaming mice.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this particular software, however similar one from Logitech, stores mouse button mappings in *.xml files in its `ApplicationData` directory. Try to check out the install directory of your software and `ApplicationData` and see if you can find anything there.

Answer (score 1):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is your friend. Create a filter in it for your mouse software and see what files and what registry entries it accesses. You are only interested in the few seconds while the mouse program starts, then you can press CTRL+E to stop capturing events.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a piece of software, like you say you are, you can only swap the left and right buttons in Control Panel > Mouse. The software is more of a controller than a driver, and keeps the settings in the software, rather than messing with the registry.